# Breeze doesn't expand more than one navigation property path?

Tags: breeze

if I run the following query using the NorthindModel, NorthwindDataContext from the breeze samples only the first navigation property is expaned. All other returning null:

```
    var query = EntityQuery.from("OrderDetails")
        .where("OrderID", "==", 11069)
        .expand("Order.Customer", "Order.Employee");
    manager.executeQuery(query).then(querySucceeded).fail(queryFailed);

    function querySucceeded(data){
         var customer = data.results[0].Order().Customer();
         var employee = data.results[0].Order().Employee(); // returns null!!!!!
    }
```

If I change the order in the expand paramerter list than customer is set to null:

```
    var query = EntityQuery.from("OrderDetails")
        .where("OrderID", "==", 11069)
        .expand("Order.Employee", "Order.Customer");
    manager.executeQuery(query).then(querySucceeded).fail(queryFailed);

    function querySucceeded(data){
         var customer = data.results[0].Order().Customer(); // returns null!!!!!
         var employee = data.results[0].Order().Employee();         }
```

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The 'expand' method takes a single argument that is either an array or a comma delimited string. You gave it two arguments.  So try the following instead.

var query = EntityQuery.from("OrderDetails")
        .where("OrderID", "==", 11069)
        ***.expand(["Order.Customer", "Order.Employee"]);***

Note the [].

Comment: Ok, the docs on breeze.js seems to be a mess....that took me hours.
http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/navigation-properties

Comment: The API Docs are sometimes a better place to look:  http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityQuery.html#method_expand

Comment: I updated the commentary on `expand` in [breezejs.com/documentation/navigation-properties](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/navigation-properties) in hopes that the next person does not struggle as you did. Is there something else we can do to make this more clear? Thanks for the feedback.